# Schur Index Divisibility Question: Ind A^E divides Ind A

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

Background notation: If $A\in\mathcal{F}$ is a central simple algebra, $A\cong M_n(D)$, where $D$ is a division algebra. The Schur index of $A$ is defined as $Ind(A)=Deg(D)$.

**How do we prove $A^E$ divides $Ind(A)$?** (We may assume further assume that $A$ is a division algebra). $A^E:=A\otimes E$, where $E$ is an extension field of $F$.

According to Richard Pierce's book, it is supposed to follow easily from the following result (ii): $Ind(A)$ divides $Deg(A)$, and $Ind(A)=Deg(A)$ if and only if $A$ is a division algebra.

My workings:
I managed to prove (ii) as follows: $Deg(A)=nDeg(D)=nInd(A)$, so $Ind(A)\mid Deg(A)$. $Ind(A)=Deg(A)$, iff $n=1$, so $A\cong D$.

Then, 
$$
Ind(A^E)\mid Deg(A\otimes E)
$$
and I am stuck here. Can I claim that $A\otimes E\cong A$, and thus finish it off?

Comment: Have you covered the fact that $D\otimes E$ is a central simple algebra over $E$? It then follows (by Wedderburn) that
$$D\otimes E\simeq M_k(D_E)$$ for some division algebra $D_E$ with center $E$. Calculating the dimensions should tell you that the degree of $D_E$ must a factor of the degree of $D$. This is pretty much what you want to prove, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks. Is $D_E$ isomorphic to $D\otimes E$?

Comment: No. $D\otimes E$ is isomorphic to $M_k(D_E)$. If $k>1$, then this is not isomorphic to $D_E$.  In general we don't know what $D_E$ is. It is just some division algebra with center $E$. You do need it to calculate the index of $A^E$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Just a question, how do we know that the division algebra must be of the form $D_E$ with center $E$? The version of Wedderburn I see just mentions it is a division algebra without specifying the center. (I have a feeling it is trivial but I can't see it)

Comment: The center of the matrix algebra $M_n(D)$ can easily seen to be isomorphic to the center of $D$ (viewed as scalar matrices). And also the center of the tensor product $A\otimes_F B$ is the subspace $c(A)\otimes_F c(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly recall the definitions, then

1. $\dim_FD=(\deg D)^2$ (this holds for all division algebras that are
   f.d. over their center).
2. $\dim_E A^E=\dim_F A$ (this is obvious).
3. If $D$ is a division algebra with center
   $F$, then $D\otimes_F E$ is a central simple algebra with center $E$. Therefore, by Wedderburn's Theorem, 
   $$D\otimes_FE\simeq M_k(D_E)$$ for some division algebra $D_E$ with center $E$.
4. So $$k^2\dim_E D_E= \dim_E M_k(D_E)=\dim_E(D\otimes_FE)=\dim_F D.$$
5. Combining items 1 and 4 gives us $$(\deg D)^2=\dim_F D=k^2\dim_E D_E=k^2(\deg D_E)^2,$$ and consequently $$\deg D= k\cdot \deg D_E.$$
6. So $\deg D_E\mid \deg D$.

By your definition $\operatorname{Ind}(A)=\deg D$ and $\operatorname{Ind}(A^E)=\deg D_E$, so we are done.

Comment: Thanks again. Just to ask why is $dim_E A^E=dim_F A$ obvious?